# How to retrieve a comment object from an Excel cell in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

I have always used `Range.Comment` and `Range.SpecialCells` to retrieve comments inside Excel sheets however it seems it doesn't work anymore.
It looks like every online solution I could read uses `Range.Comment` just like me so I have set up a reproducible case to check whether it works or not:

- Follow the [Microsoft Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) instructions to create a new VSTO add-in with an XML ribbon
  (I used .NET Framework 4.7.2 as well as 4.8)
- Replace the `tabs` element of `MyRibbon.xml` with this code:

  ```xml
  <tabs>
     <tab id="MyAddinTab" label="MyAddin">
        <group id="Stuff" label="Content">
           <button id="MyButton" label="Do stuff" onAction="DoStuff" size="large" imageMso="FileServerMenu"/>
        </group>
     </tab>
  </tabs>
  ```
- In `MyRibbon.cs` add the following code in the callback section:

  ```cs
  public void DoStuff(Office.IRibbonControl control)
  {
      Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
      Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);
      Comment comment = range.Comment;

      int debugBreakpoint = 0; // Put a breakpoint here
  }
  ```
- Set a breakpoint in `MyRibbon.cs` at the `int` declaration
- Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to start the add-in, open a new workbook
- Right click on cell A1 and add a comment
- Find the add-in in the ribbon, click the button

When you inspect the `comment` variable, it is `null` although there is a comment in it.
This is a simplistic example, I noticed this behavior because a function that uses `Range.SpecialCells` which was tested and worked before now doesn't.
You can update this example to use it instead of a `Range.Comment` line, nothing will be retrieved.

So my question is: **did something change?**
The internet is full of posts saying this is the right way to retrieve a comment in a cell, was there some kind of update to it?

**EDIT**

Apparently I was kind of misled.
`Range.Comment` retrieves notes, not actual comments, the latter are called [CommentThreaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.commentthreaded).

Moreover when using `Range.SpecialCells` the [XlCellType documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlcelltype?view=excel-pia) states that `XlCellType.xlCellTypeComments` is for retrieving notes.
There is no enumeration to retrieve threaded comments.

The designation is ambiguous because [comments and notes were made distinct](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-difference-between-threaded-comments-and-notes-75a51eec-4092-42ab-abf8-7669077b7be3), however you can still manage notes in C# by using calls to `Range.Comment` and `Range.NoteText`.
The reason I thought I was handling comments before is because the mentioned code is all about comments and was written before the distinction existed.

To manage and retrieve threaded comments, you must use the corresponding API, but I have no access to it via Visual Studio at the moment although I can see it when inspecting `Range` objects in debug.
An alternative is to use the [VBA version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.commentsthreaded) which I tested and works.

Comment: Is `Range("A1").Comment` also `Nothing` in VBA?

Comment: @GSerg, yes it is.

Comment: Then either you are accessing a wrong sheet, or MS has broken Excel in a yet another way and will or will not fix it in six months (not unless millions complain, that is).

Answer (score 0):

> The internet is full of posts saying this is the right way to retrieve a comment in a cell, was there some kind of update to it?

Even if that is the right way of adding comments, you get the `ActiveSheet` property value in the ribbon callback which could lead to unpredictable results:

```
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
```

That can lead to a wrong sheet used for adding a comment in the code. It is not necessary the active sheet will be the one which caused the callback invoked.

The [IRibbonControl.Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribboncontrol.context) property represents the active window containing the Ribbon user interface that triggers a callback procedure. If you try to use this property of the object passed as an argument to the ribbon callback you will always deal with the right Excel sheet.

Comment: In the minimal repro step I provided, only 1 workbook and worksheet exist, therefore the only ActiveSheet that can be retrieved is the one containing the comment. I had already checked it was the right range by writing a value in the cell and checking it on debug mode, but didn't report it in my post.
However for the sake of listening to your advice I reproduced the test by using direct reference and calling the workbook and worksheet by name, and the result is still the same. I didn't use IRibbonControl.Context because the documentation is unusable as is.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the Excel object model. Try opening a support case with MS for that.